# Can I have a do while statement in C++ that checks for both a character and a int value before looping?

Tags: c++, loops

I very new at this and have an assignment in which I would like for a loop to exit if the user inputs(trans) 'e' but also end if a calculation balance(bal) is less than a constant I have set. Basically as my question states one is a character and the other an integer, will that work? I'm not trying to get people to do my homework for me, so I'm not posting all of my code or assignment, hope it makes sense.

```
This is the line of code I have
do { 
ask user input(&trans)
e or calculation
{
while (trans != 'e'| bal < -OVR);
```

Comment: You could try this and see for yourself no? Trying is the best way to learn

Comment: if (condition) do {...} while(...) ?

Comment: Each condition will evaluate to a `bool`, so if you're worried about a type mismatch there's none there. Just be sure to actually use the logic operators `||` and `&&` and not the bitwise ones `|` and `&`.

Comment: Be warned, you have a `{` instead of a `}`.

Comment: Typo sorry, and the thing is I did try it, but even though I got no build errors my program goes off the rails and I wasn't sure if this was the weak point. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use regular unconditional loop and multiple exit conditions:

```
while( true ) {
   char trans;
   std::cin >> trans;
   if( !std::cin or trans == 'e' ) 
       break;
   calculation;
   if( bal > -0VR )
       break;
}
```

So first of all you would not do unnecessary calculations, but what is more important you would make your code more readable and easier to understand - you make loop exit decision where it should be instead of pushing it into the end.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to work with std and cin, but I do understand what you mean by pushing decisions to end of the code. Thanks!